# Opacity with PHP

Tags: php, html, css, opacity

Is it possible to hide a part of website like `DIV` or any tag with `opacity` & `z-index` in PHP instead of CSS

CSS Code:

```
#unwantedposition{
    opacity:0;
    z-index:9999;
    position:absolute;
    }
```

I am trying to rewrite my CSS code with PHP

PHP Code:

```
header("Content-type: text/css; charset: UTF-8");

   $opacity = "0";
   $z-index = "9999";
   $position = "absolute";
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: yes you can use if statement for that

Comment: PHP has no access to DOM. Opacity, z-index and position are CSS properties. You can, however, output valid CSS with PHP.

Comment: @Jerson Can you show me example. how i can write `if statement` for `opacity` and `z-index`.

Comment: @MarkusAO so there is no way to use `opacity` and `z-index` with PHP?

Comment: As noted, they are **CSS properties**. The "p" in PHP stands for "preprocessor". You can use PHP to produce valid HTML, CSS,  Javascript, and anything else that the browser understands. PHP is not a front-end language and does not run in the browser.

Comment: @MarkusAO i know what PHP means. i am just asking if any way to make content transparent using PHP

Comment: Have you understood what PHP does, in general, though?

Comment: @shanmugapradeep, you can make content transparent using PHP by adding CSS properties to `style` attribute or adding CSS class with required properties to target element

Comment: @7-zete-7 can you show some example? how can i write these statement with PHP

Comment: @shanmugapradeep, watch on answer

Comment: I'm finding it very unclear what you want to achieve. From comments in some of the answers it sounds as though you are trying to make sure that a user cannot view your source code. This is not possible - but is it what you are wanting to achieve? Also the concept of 'opacity in PHP' has no meaning.

Answer (score 0):

Try to achieve this with if statement example under the body the variable `$hide` set it on top of your html page

```
<style type="text/css">
    .disabled-div {
        pointer-events: none;
        opacity: 0.4;
    }
</style>
<body>
    
    <div class="<?php if($hide === true){ ?>disabled-div <?php } ?>">this is my hidden div</div>
    
    <div>some content</div>
</body>
```

Comment: Your code will disabled (hide) the `DIV` means the content of DIV will not print on client side but i want to hide as transparent like `opacity` in `CSS `

Comment: @shanmugapradeep I've updated my answer, I think it will fit better what you are looking for

Answer (score 0):

You could simply override that CSS class.

```php
<?php
echo '<style>
    #unwantedposition{
    opacity:0;
    z-index:9999;
    position:absolute;
}
</style>';
```

That should be placed in your header tag, below your CSS file.

Comment: But it same thing. i am looking for alternative solution without use of CSS.

Comment: The easiest way to do this, is with JavaScript. If you want to do it with PHP only, it is possible but way too heavy. First, you will need to read your CSS file. With Regex you will need to find the string that you are looking for, then with PHP replacing it with the new string. Once that is done, save the new string in the same file and load the page.

Answer (score 0):

You can conditionally show HTML tag:

```php
<?php if ($isNeedToShow): ?>
  <div>...</div>
<?php endif ?>
```

Comment: It just another way of using CSS using PHP but i am looking for same kind of function with PHP without CSS because i do not want opacity code in view-source.

Comment: @shanmugapradeep, PHP can only avoid the rendering of the HTML tag. To hide an element you must use CSS.

Comment: Writing in CSS will not hide the element in view-source :(. anyone can click view source in browser and read the CSS with opacity mentioned or the CSS link which is called in the page.

Comment: @shanmugapradeep, 
in this case, you just need to not render the HTML tag. Watch the changed answer

Comment: If it appears in the DOM/HTML, it will obviously be present in the "view-source" (with CSS or otherwise). Even if you render it using javascript, the generated HTML will still be readable with basic developer tools.

Comment: @MarkusAO, I don't even want to bring up the topic of Shadow DOM. 
Although even it can be viewed :)

Comment: @shanmugapradeep, you can use WebAssemply, Canvas, Shadow DOM or etc to "hide" elements, but one way or another, they will still be visible because HTML + CSS + JS - open source

Comment: `<?php echo DOMElement::setDarkMatterNode('embed', 'QuestionableUseCase');`. Really though, just render it as an image if the text content shouldn't show in the source. (And then hide it? For what purpose do we want to make invisible things that can't be found in the HTML source? I'm fascinated.)

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand what you mean.
However, `opacity` and `z-index` are CSS properties.
However, PHP doesn't have access to the `DOM Element`, it can only use a mix of HTML and CSS.

Then the question is, how to use PHP to mix HTML and CSS?

You can print `<tag style="css-property: value;"></tag>`
Example :

```
<div style="opacity: 0; z-index: 9999; position: absolute"></div>
```

Did this answer help? If you have other questions you can add comments about your questions.